# Multiple sed commands into one

Tags: sed

I have 3 sed commands. How to combine the below sed commands?

```
sed -e '15,19d' 
sed -n '/something/,+16p' 
sed -e '1712,1747d'
```

I want to combine them say something like this

```
sed -e 'command1' -e 'command2' -e 'command3'
```

But it is not working because -n can't be combine.

Comment: Just combine the different commands with semicolons: `sed -n '15,19d; /something/,+16p'`. I'm not sure about the last command because if they are executed in the shown order, the last one looks indeterministic. Either case, you can just append it with another semicolon.

Comment: You can achieve the same result as `sed -n '/something/,+16p' file` with `sed '/something/,+16!d' file` and then join the other two commands by `;` in GNU sed. But I am guessing you do not want this. Perhaps an example of the output from your commands might clarify the problem.

Comment: I do not understand, so `-n '/something/,+16p' ` removes _all_ lines except something and 16 lines. Just `-n '/something/,+16p'` any other lines will be removed anyway. What is the precedence between commands? What should happen when `something` is in line 17?

Comment: In the order given, if there's `something` in the lines 15-19, it won't be matched by the second command, so it might be relevant. But I don't really see the third command, I also have precedence issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a single command,

```
sed -ne '/something/,+16p'
```

is the same as

```
sed -e '/something/,+16!d'
```

i.e. *don't delete 16 lines after something*.

But combining them into one command

```
sed -e '15,19d' -e '/something/,+16!d' -e '1712,1747d
```

might give different results when "something" appears before line 15.

Why? You need to understand how sed works. It reads the input line by line and for each line, it decides which rules are applicable. If `something` appears before line 15, it starts printing from there, because the second rule matches; but stops printing from line 15 because of the first rule. In the original pipeline, though, the lines are removed first, so `+16` extends over some more lines that weren't printed.

I don't see a way how to fix this problem in sed.

Demo:

```
#!/bin/bash
input() {
    printf 'A %d\n' {1..10}
    echo something
    printf 'B %d\n' {1..20}
}

diff -y <(
    input | sed -e '15,19d' | sed -ne '/something/,+16p'
) <(
    input | sed -e '15,19d;/something/,+16!d'
)
```